Deleting remote branch after git merge origin/main?
I created a remote branch lets say "branch_a" off of origin/main. Then to keep the branch upto date, I did:
git fetch origin
git merge origin/main

I hope that's one of the right ways? I mean git rebase would also do. But git merge origin/main is also legal I assume?
Basically its "Merge remote-tracking origin/main into branch_a" is what I see in gitlab after I do those commands. Yes I use gitlab.
Now question is it is safe to delete this remote branch branch_a without affecting anything right?
Please suggest best practice if I did something incorrect.

Basically its "Merge remote-tracking origin/main into branch_a" is what I see in gitlab after I do those commands - you also did git push, didn't you?

Yes I did git push too.

And you did git merge origin/main while you were on branch_a?

Yes I did a git merge origin/main while on branch_a and no body uses branch_a

right, see my answer then


Now question is it is safe to delete this remote branch branch_a
without affecting anything right?

Well it depends on multiple factors and what does without affecting
anything mean.
Users who ran git fetch while the branch existed will have it listed
in git branch -r forever until they run git fetch --prune. It only
takes space and might be confusing but will not break anything.
Users who created a local branch from it and let Git set up remote
branch automatically with git checkout <BRANCH> will not be able to
pull from it any more.
Any PRs that were open against this branch should be immediately
closed, at least that's what Bibucket and GitHub are doing.
Pushing a new branch may trigger CI systems build, depending on how
it's configured and how many times it pulls the repository it may
crash at some point because the commit on the tip of the branch was
gone.
These won't be serious issues in most cases, especially if you didn't ask
anyone to check out the branch (still, some users may do that on their
own). And if you have it locally and someone else might need it again
you can re-push it or restore it from reflog within the next 30 days.

what does "Pushing a new branch may trigger CI systems build, depending on how it's configured and how many times it pulls the repository it may crash at some point because the commit on the tip of the branch was gone." mean? No one will use this branch as this is experimental. So I can just delete it right?

CI systems such as Bamboo, CircleCI etc. are able to start building
pipeline on the branch even if PR hasn't been opened. Some of them,
like Bamboo, can run different stages on different hosts and pull the
repository multiple times but more or less in the same time. There is
also a possibility that the definition of your CI pipeline involves
pushing something to the same branch in repository - this of course
won't work if the branch is deleted when pushing is done (but normally
CI pipeline takes at most like 30 minutes and you would see it if you
got new commits on the branch after ...

... doing git pull.) or to a stable
branch in the repository but it's unlikely and should happen only on
specific PRs or branches.

And regarding No one will use this branch as this is experimental -
well, you never know that but if you didn't advertise this branch as
the new public branch to pull from and, for example review changes you
can remove it.

Actually, I do this quite often myself when I work on a new feature. I
create a branch and push it to the remote and commit often but I don't
open a PR yet. Then, when the feature is ready I clean up the commit
messages, remove all debug logs etc. and remove the work in progress branch. It's useful because you have a backup of your work on a
remote server.

And, one more thing - GitLab should not allow you to remove a stable
branch which is usually protected unless you're the admin of
everything in your company so there is even less to be worried about.

Got it. You got my upvote. thanks.

@is there anything that's preventing you from accepting your favorite answer?

Yes, it is safe to delete a remote branch (branch_a) after merging the main branch into it. You merged main into branch_a meaning that branch_a is now updated with all changes from main. If you have any new changes that are important in the branch_a make sure you make a pull request to the main before deleting the branch_a locally or remotely.
